# Heroku and Web scraping

Tags: ruby, web-services, api, heroku, sinatra

I have a nokigiri web scraper that publishes to a database that I'm trying to publish to heroku. I have a sinatra application frontend that I want to have pull in from the database. I'm new to Heroku and web development, and don't know the best way to handle something like this.

Do I have to place the web scraper script that uploads to the database under a sinatra route (like mywebsite.com/scraper ) and just make it so obscure that no one visits it? In the end, I'd like to have the sinatra part be a rest api that pulls from the database.

Thanks for all input

Comment: It depends how often you want it to fire - on command, at a certain time…?

Comment: Your question needs a little more information to be answered. Do you want to scrape from within heroku? What is the function of /scraper, is it to kick off the scraping script or to retrieve scraped contents?  Are you more concerned about how to secure an http endpoint than how to host an app on heroku?

Answer (score 3):

There are two approaches you can take.

The first one is to use One-off dynos by running the scraper through the console using `heroku run YOURCMD`. Just make sure scraper don't write to disk but uses database.

More information:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos

The second is differentiating between scraper and web process in a way that you have web process for normal UI interaction and a scraper process which web process can spawn/talk to. If you take this route it's up to you how to protect it from rest of the world (auth/url obfuscation etc.).

More information:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing

Answer (score 0):

I did it by creating a rake task and using the one-off dynos as mentioned by XLII

Here is my rake task file

```
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require

desc "Scrape Site"
 task :scrape, [:companyname]  => :environment do |t, args|
    puts "Company Name is :" + args[:companyname]

    agent = Mechanize.new
    agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
    puts "Agent (Mac Safari Created)"
        # MORE SCRAPING CODE

 end
```

You can simply run it by call

```
heroku run rake scrape[google]
```