# Easiest way to running Python code on the cloud

Tags: python, cloud

I have certain web scraping Python code that using some module below

- selenium
- bs4
- MySQLdb
- apscheduler

What is the easiest way or platform to running my code online or on the cloud?

Answer (score 0):

Try https://www.pythonanywhere.com  they provide full python environment to run your code on the cloud. They also have a limited account which you can try for free

Comment: but pyhtonanywhere doesn't support apscheduler

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the already mentioned [pythonanywhere.com](http://www.pythonanywhere.com), other alternatives I found are:

- [scrapinghub.com](https://scrapinghub.com/)
- [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/) (see related SO questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640532/python-database-without-using-django-for-heroku?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605833/heroku-and-web-scraping))